# MongoDB adding years in existing ISODate field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB collection with documents containing timestamp which is ISO Date.

Somehow these dates got messed up while inserting and now they are in 1970!
I have fixed my inserting code. Now it is inserting correct timestamp.

But i need to fix the old data whose dates are in 1970 now. I need to add a specific time period in the timestamp of each record. Like 46 years and 5 months to change it to 2016 June.

e.g
**Current timestamp:**
`"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`

**New timestamp:**
`"timestamp": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"

**and then increase timestamp of next by 10 seconds**

`"timestamp": "2016-06-01T00:00:20.000Z"`
`"timestamp": "2016-06-01T00:00:30.000Z"`

and so on...
Is is possible from mongo shell? If not, what else can i use?

Comment: Hard to follow without clear-cut examples. Can you please edit your question to include your existing code for inserting new documents, perhaps some sample documents from your collection that are exhibiting the issue?

Comment: @chridam, sorry i was unclear. I have fixed my insert. What i need is, how do i update my 1970 ISODates and add 46 years to them. Need to increment each one by 10 seconds from last one.

Comment: I am interested with your original problem, what was it? Shouldn't the dates be corrected when you fixed the insertions as well?

Comment: @kazenorin, yes, the new incoming data has correct timestamps. I need to correct the old ones. See updated question

Comment: So you need to artificially increase those 1970's record by increments of 10 seconds?

Comment: Never change your question drastically, this totally not what you was asking in the beginning!!

Comment: @kazenorin there is no timestamp type, it's a date with min year/month/days which is as always stored  as Date

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, you're right. Should've posted another question.

Comment: @kazenorin, yes. I need to increase those timestamps by 10 seconds, one after another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// for demo, create a record with some date
> db.so.insert({_id: new ObjectId(), date: new Date(1970, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10)})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

// be sure it's created
> db.so.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576ceec5827bed78eaa65cc6"), "date" : ISODate("1970-02-01T04:10:10Z") }

// docs.forEach => update.doc.date => new Date(oldDate: hours, minutes, seconds)
> db.so.find().forEach(function(doc) { var date = doc.date; db.so.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {date: new Date(2016, 5, date.getDay(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds())}}) })
```

I use

```
col.find().forEach(){ col.update() }
```

because you need the old date of document, if you don't bother with old date, you can use

```
db.so.update({}, {$set: {date: new Date()}})
```

Or even better use $currentDate operator

```
db.so.update({}, {$currentDate: {date: {$type: 'date'}}})
```

Read more in mongo doc [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)

Comment: This is great. But i realized i will need to increment it as i go on.
Will `date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds+10)` work?

Comment: Yes, mongo repl is node repl, which is javascript repl

Comment: Actually no, i dont need current date.
Need to turn `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z` into `1970-06-22 00:00:00.000Z`and increase 10 seconds in each record

Comment: So what's the problem. answer covers your needs, i would do it in 2 iterations, in first: convert year/month/date, in second: increment seconds, just simply make a variable outside of `.forEach`, increase it inside, and assign to `$set`

Comment: yes, it does cover, just pointed out that i dont need current date. the previous part is all i need.

Comment: One problem though, when i increment seconds everytime by 10, the timestamp gets changed a lot.

These are first 3 timestamps:
`2016-07-22 02:46:40.000Z`,
`2016-07-22 05:33:20.000Z`,
`2016-07-22 08:20:00.000Z`

Comment: 1s = 1000 milliseconds, timestamp is milliseconds, check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115508/discussion-between-dushyant-bangal-and-medet-tleukabiluly).